# Query on All Items view in SharePoint 2013

Tags: list-view, query, list-item

I need to query on AllItems view for getting items. How can I do this? CAML maybee?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately my reputation is not enough for commenting...

If you want only filter your table, then use the different Filter Webparts in Sharepoint. 
There are different Filters for input fields, GET-Parameters, etc.

But, you can't use any filter for any lists. You have to try it.

I hope, that helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Get the CAML query of ANY VIEW by following PowerShell

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity "Site URL goes here";
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["List Name"];
$spView = $spList.Views["View Name"];
$spView.Query | Out-File "Path with file name"
```

**or**

Make a GET request to following end-point using any rest client

```
http://Site URL/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('List Name')/Views/getbytitle('View Name')?$select=ViewQuery
```

Learn [more](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993035/Building-CAML-for-querying-List-in-SharePoint)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question, but if you want to query a list for items in specific columns depending on different circumstances, you should use CAMLQuery

[U2U CAMLQuery helper](http://www.u2u.be/Software) is a nice tool to get started.